# ASP.Net Custom Control use embeded resource filename in a script?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, custom-controls

I have a custom control that has some embedded resources. I need to be able to reference some of the embedded material outside the control in JavaScript. So let's say I have an image file embedded in the control and I have a script outside the control that will do something with that file. How do I reference that file name outside the control?

Update: Not sure if this is even possible and I have not found any information on it. Anyone have an idea? Maybe I create functions inside the embedded JS to get access to those files?

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131200/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080906-1.aspx) what you are looking for??  It looks like you can use the GetWebResourceURL from the ClientScriptManager class to do this.

Comment: I believe that is used to create the refernece from an embeded file via teh backend. I am looking to call an embeded file from an external source. If I know an image exists inside the library, how do I access it?

Comment: So you mean from outside the application completely??  From another website or application?

Comment: No, not that far out ;) On the current page that I am using the control. So, if there is an embeded image, is there a way to get to it from, say, JavaScrtipt or by adding an image tag to the page.

Comment: You should just be able to do the following in the asp.net page (not the code behind):  var url=<%=GetWebResourceURL(type, resourcename) %> and put the url in a javascript variable.  You may need to put the call to getwebresourceurl in a public property on the page object though.  Try that and see if it works.